# How insert additional values to SQLite into BLOB column?

Tags: sqlite, blob

I have a table with name "vehicles" and column "status" with BLOB type,

inside in column I have this values:

```
{"status": "available", "condition": "new"}
```

Can some help understand how I can replace values into that column to this one

```
{"status": "available", "condition": "new", "color": 'red'}
```

sometimes I need to insert new values and sometimes remove some values,
can somebody please help me write the query to that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is JSON, which is a textual format, so you should be storing it as text, not blobs. Doing so means you can use the sqlite [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension's functions to make manipulating the values easy.

Examples:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE vehicles(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, status);
sqlite> INSERT INTO vehicles(status) VALUES ('{"status": "available", "condition": "new"}');
sqlite> UPDATE vehicles SET status = json_insert(status, '$.color', 'red') WHERE id = 1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM vehicles;
id          status                                                
----------  ------------------------------------------------------
1           {"status":"available","condition":"new","color":"red"}
sqlite> UPDATE vehicles SET status = json_remove(status, '$.condition') WHERE id = 1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM vehicles;
id          status                              
----------  ------------------------------------
1           {"status":"available","color":"red"}
```